# Как обновить параметр потока во время его работы?

Tags: delphi, многопоточность

Передаю параметры при создании потока

```
FThread[I] := Thread.Create(true, parametr);
```

Хотелось бы поставить поток на паузу и впилить туда обновленный параметр, как это реализовать?

```
    constructor Thread.Create(FStat: Boolean; Fparametrs : string);
    begin
      inherited Create(FStat);
      FreeOnTerminate := True;
      Priority        := tpNormal;
      FProxyTypes     := strtoint(pars('ProxyType:',Fparametrs,'"'));
      allpar          := Fparametrs;

      Resume;

    end;
```

Comment: Уточните, с какой конкретно целью вы хотите поставить поток на паузу - для безопасного обновления параметра или для чего-то еще?

Comment: и уточните, как вы используете этот параметр в потоке.

Comment: Смотрите я запустил поток с параметром (в параметре ссылка т.е обычный string), он работает к примеру час, затем я решил чтобы этот поток (без полного перезапуска потоков) получил от меня другую ссылку. Т.е во время работы потока мне нужно залить в него новую ссылку.  НО речь идет о 100-400 потоках, поэтому использовать критичку в каждом чтобы спарсить с формы строку, будет сильно замедлять потоки

Comment: constructor Thread.Create(FStat: Boolean; Fparametrs : string);
begin
  inherited Create(FStat);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  Priority        := tpNormal;
  FProxyTypes     := strtoint(pars('ProxyType:',Fparametrs,'"'));
  MaxError        := strtoint(pars('ErrorMax:',Fparametrs,'"'));
  OSTSTR          := strtoint(pars('Ost:',Fparametrs,'"'));
  TimeOut         := strtoint(pars('timoute:',Fparametrs,'"'));
  allpar          := Fparametrs;

  Resume;

end;  Вот так я использую

Answer (score 2):

Добавляете в поток процедуру, которая принимает ваш обновленный параметр и в ней записываете его в поле потока. Чтение и запись поля должны быть обернуты в **критичесую секцию**, чтобы вы могли всегда контролировать момент записи и чтения, чтобы они не могли наложиться друг на друга (иначе получите источник необъяснимых Хейзенбагов).

Если поле простое (булевый флаг, число), вы его только читаете в потоке, и вы его не используете в сложной логике (не может ли ее "сломать" непредсказуемое изменение параметра на полпути), то можете писать значение напрямую.

P.S. Естественно, подобные операции можно делать только на управляемых (несамоубивающихся) потоках, когда у вас есть гарантия того, что поток не будет освобожден в момент обращения к нему.

Comment: > _Если поле простое, то можете писать значение на прямую_ - к сожалению "простота" только уменьшает вероятность коллизий. Простой inc(i) внутри потоков на четырехядерной машине в моем эксперименте сбоил в 1% случаев. Думаю, что и вне потока будет так же.

Comment: @VladChapl написано же _только читаете в потоке_. А "простой inc(i)" не только читает, но и записывает новое значение.

Comment: а если человек использует этот параметр в логике, тогда что? То есть допустим, поток в цикле выполняет расчет, свойство используется в цикле несколько раз. То есть нельзя допустить, чтобы значение изменилось в процессе итерации.

Comment: @teran это уже автору надо думать, сложная у него логика или нет, и как ее может "сломать" непредсказуемое изменение параметра на полпути.

Comment: Эт я к тому, что КС не панацея, и возможно не слишком то здесь и подходит. в данном случае нет классической ситуации, где куча потоков используют общий ресурс. Тут на сколько я понимаю один управляющий поток, и один рабочий. Ну или мб много рабочих, но параметр это не общий ресурс всех рабочих потоков. В этом смысле вопрос достаточно общий, чтобы дать конкретный ответ.

Comment: в случае простых типов и циклического множественного использования, значение параметра можно копировать в локальную переменную, и брать новое значение при старте итерации. В случае ссылочных, наоборот записывать в дублирующее свойство.

Answer (score 0):

Приостанавливать поток **никогда** не нужно (разве только для теста). Можно и не добавлять процедуру в поток. Создайте глобальную переменную **parametr** и обращение к ней оберните в критическую секцию.